# Pandas df to Rss Feed?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, rss

I currently have a script that queries a database and formats the result into a dataframe that I .to_excel but I was wondering if it is possible to have this dataframe be output to an RSS feed?  I'm new to RSS feeds so sorry if this makes no sense.

I have seen a post on here about outputting an excel as an RSS but nothing about a Pandas Dataframe. Currently have only output my dataframe to an excel spreadsheet

Greatly appreciate any replies

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.